# Function that runs perfectly fine outside of QGIS keeps crashing QGIS (3.16) Python 3.7

Tags: qgis-3, qgis-plugins, geopandas

I'm very new to QGIS, PyQt and even Python so I'm sorry if there is a very obvious mistake I am making, but I can seem to get one of my functions to run from within a plugin I'm writing for QGIS (3.16). When I run it directly from a test main as a script it functions perfectly fine. Ultimately, I would like to run it on a separate thread but for now, it even crashes QGIS when run on the main thread. (it also crashes QGIS when ran from a separate thread, I have tried it with QgsTask.fromFunction and TaskManager as well as PyQt5's `ThreadPool` and `QRunnable` subclass).

What I'm wondering about is the following: when I call the exact same function from a test main that I made, from within a virtual environment that is exactly the same as the QGIS Python setup, it runs just fine. I can obviously share some of my code, but I was wondering whether that fact alone pointed to something I'm missing. The line of code that seems to be causing the crash calls geopandas `sjoin`.

Further relevant information:

Both dataframes involved in the `sjoin` are created within the function that I want to run, so I doubt it's a matter of scope?

I have a general try/except clause set up that should catch (and currently print and ignore) all exceptions. However, that doesn't seem to prevent the crash.

The structure of the code:

```
pluginclass.run()
    button.clicked.connect(parent_of_crasher)

parent_of_crasher calls crasher

crasher calls subfunction_of_crasher
```

In my test main, I just call the function directly from main.

One argument is being passed to the crashing function (a python class object), but it's passed to every function I call from the parent and hasn't created any issues anywhere else, so I'm pretty sure that isn't the problem.

Where it crashes:

```
#(fixeddrainage and conn_nodes_geo are both geodataframes passed into the subfunction_of_crasher by the 'crasher')
try:
   joined = sjoin(
                fixeddrainage, conn_nodes_geo, how='left', op='intersects', lsuffix='fd', rsuffix='conn')

except Exception as e:
   QgsMessageLog(e)
   raise e from None

#After testing it on a hunch: it also crashes on
    overl = overlay(fixeddrainage, conn_nodes_geo, how="intersection")
```

I can print and modify both `fixeddrainage` and `conn_nodes_geo` without crashing QGIS, which leads me to believe it's not a memory/scope issue (I tried it by renaming columns in place, and doing a groupby). Furthermore, it never prints an exception to the message log, even when I pass instead of raising the exception.

It does seem to only happen with geopandas functions.

I am really at a loss here, so any insight is very welcome! I can provide more detailed information if that would help, but I figured I would describe the outline in case it points to a common mistake!

Edit: geopandas version is 0.8.1 in case that is relevant.

Edit: I have been experimenting further and I have found the following does work:

```
for index, row in fixeddrainage.iterrows():
    nodes_in_area = conn_nodes_geo.intersection(row.geometry)
    nodes_in_area_index = nodes_in_area[~nodes_in_area.is_empty].index 

    fixeddrainage.loc[index, 'area_nodes_m2'] = round(
        conn_nodes_geo.loc[nodes_in_area_index, 'storage_area'].sum(), 0)
```

While this:

```
joined = sjoin(
            fixeddrainage, conn_nodes_geo, how='left', op='intersects', lsuffix='fd', rsuffix='conn')

group = joined.groupby([peil_id, 'multipolygon_level'])[storage_area].sum()

fixeddrainage = fixeddrainage.merge(group, how='left', on=[peil_id, 'multipolygon_level'])
```

However, I would rather not use the iterrows method. Can anyone tell me what the difference is (keeping in mind that the function executes fine outside of qgis) between the two methods?

Answer (score 1):

In case someone else runs into this issue: in my case, upgrading the Rtree package to version 0.9.7 fixed it.